# Return Google Maps API response indicating tolls

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Google Maps API can accepts a restriction of no tolls (avoid=tolls). What I am not finding is how to not include this restriction and for the responses to each include an indication of if they include tolls or not.

For example: Driving from A to B has a toll road and non-toll route. I want to get both routes back and be able to identify which one includes a section on the toll road.